# Problem with Bluetooth after removing 'brltty' package

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem with Bluetooth on my Laptop. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. It has always worked very well but yesterday i try to connect my ESP82 on my PC but for allow the detection with USB connection I find a topic who say to remove the package `brltty` and after this my ESP was recognized but the Bluetooth no longer works
— it shows me "No Bluetooth Found" "Plug a dongle to use Bluetooth". I don't know what to do, I already try to reinstall it but it raise an error:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:712 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.
d/bluetooth-rtbth.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'options'
```

and **/etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth-rtbth.** is just:

`options rtbth`

Comment: In terminal try `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth-rtbth.conf && sudo modprobe rtbth`

Comment: I done it, and reinstall `brltty` but my Bluetooth still not working :/
I've try to update/upgrade and restart but noting work :/

Comment: What URL from terminal for `sudo dmesd | grep -i blue|nc termbin.com 9999`